# Why does this metallic magnetic core have so little core losses up until 100s of kHz?

Tags: transformer, electromagnetism, magnetics, loss

I have a small signal transformer with values as in the below schematic (the simulate button works well to see the AC response). The values are measured and the simulated AC response agrees sort of well with the actual behavior. In case anyone wonders about the large value of C1: It is the capacitance from two antiparallel protection diodes.

The loss resistances R2/R3 turned out so high that the signal essentially isn't attenuated at all (that's good... don't get me wrong). I expected them to be "lower" (more lossy) because of the highly conductive core material.

The core is made from VITROPERM 500F (see tables at the bottom of [this page](https://vacuumschmelze.com/Nanocrystalline-Material) for parameters).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTn784.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The core loss mechanisms in transformers that I am aware of are:

- magnetic hysteresis losses, which is the dominant loss mechanism for high resistivity ferrites up until very high frequencies
- eddy current losses which should be rather large in VITROPERM, as its resistivity is only about 100x that of copper (5-6 orders of magnitude lower than usual ferrites)

So VITROPERM should be really lossy even at intermediate frequencies due to eddy losses, and indeed the company VAC [seems to be proud of the high lossiness of VITROPERM for applications such as common-mode chokes](https://www.mouser.com/pdfdocs/VACChokesandCoresDatasheet.pdf). For example Fig. 7 in that document shows how VITROPERM is already very lossy in the dozens of kHz:
[image]

Judging from that graph, I would expect that the inductive behavior of the core essentially gives way to a dissipative one already at ~40 kHz and that magnetic coupling between primary and secondary should be greatly attenuated as a result.

Still I see two things which I guess shouldn't happen: I could also see the resonance of the leakage inductance L1 with the secondary capacitances at ~250 kHz. And for lower source impedance R1, I could also transmit much higher frequencies, 100s of kHz, without attenuation.

**So why is it, that metallic transformers are considered way too lossy for SMPS, but this transformer with a metallic core, transmits just fine up until 250 kHz?**

Comment: I don't see how anyone can answer about the values of R2 and R3 with the information you have presented.

Comment: @Andyaka well I am not looking for a quantitative "solution" for R2/R3. I am just puzzled, why this transformer **works at all** at frequencies, well beyond where its core material becomes profoundly dissipative. A lower R2/R3 would be just a schematic concept that would express such lossiness. I will reformulate that section.

Comment: Eddy current losses don't stop it operating as a transformer. I've used pieces of ferrite at hundreds of MHz to improve coupling of signals from one coil to another coil and ferrite losses at hundreds of MHz are just as bad (if not worse) than vitroperm at your frequency range.

Comment: @Andyaka I always have that mental picture in my head that Todd Hubing nicely demoes here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Zq6qiuuINE&t=375s The conductive shield inserted between a sender and receiver coil, generates an opposing magnetic field (eddy currents) reducing the coupling very severly - the essence of shielding. Could you maybe add a thought of why this might be different (or less important) in a transformer ?

Comment: That video is inapplicable as far as I can tell. The eddy current losses in the vitroperm take power from the source but, do not stop the magnetic field being coupled to the secondary. Look at the equivalent circuit for a transformer; if leakage losses are small (as you would expect with a transformer) providing the source can still apply the same voltage, the coupling of that voltage to the output via the turns ratio is unaffected.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Take a look at this cross section of a tape-wound core from https://www.magneticmetals.com/products-materials/tape-wound-toroidal-cores :

[image]

I have added the arrow to show the direction of the eddies that will result from your windings.  Notice that the eddy currents must cross many layers of the Vitroperm tape.  Each layer of tape is insulated from its adjacent layers as it is wound on, so the eddy path is interrupted.

As you go up in frequency, the eddies get smaller until eventually you can have significant eddies within the thickness of a single layer of tape.  But, tape-wound cores use tapes with thicknesses of less than a mil; 0.5 mil thicknesses are common (0.0127 mm).  So, the tape reduces eddy currents in the same fashion as laminations in larger transformers, and their upper frequency is dependent on the thickness of the tape.

Comment: Aha! I found no mention anywhere that these cores used an insulating layer. Would surely make sense for a signal transformer core. On the other hand an attenuating choke, such as a CMC, would probably do better without the insulating tape. Do you know if the insulating tape layer is always used ? Seems a bit hard to tell from the outside.

Comment: I sure don't!  Tape-wound cores were more prevalent in the days when switched-mode power supplies all operated below 100 kHz, and circuit design has progressed to where ferrites have supplanted them in many applications.  The entire idea of the tape-wound approach is to reduce losses, so I don't think you would use this approach for an intentionally lossy core.

Comment: @tobalt given the heading "Common-mode chokes and tape-wound cores" in that PDF you found, I'm guessing not :)

Comment: As I understand it, coatings include surface oxide (more so with traditional transformer iron), varnish or resin, or maybe not much at all. Note that contact resistance between layers would reduce the overall permeability (it manifests as a shorted turn in parallel with the magnetizing current) -- so CMCs are also best with insulation here.

Comment: @TimWilliams could you elaborate on that shorted turn argument ? I dont get it. the DC (LF) permeance of the core is unaffected if the type is insulated or not. What is affected is the AC losses because of eddy currents. IMO the real permeability (µ') shouldn't be affected either.

Comment: @tobalt Consider permeability as a function of frequency (as the mu', mu'' plot above): eddy currents shift the curve leftwards.  Hence, acting as a shorted turn.  Note that mu ~ 1/f is equivalent to Z ~ constant, and flat impedance has a phase of 0 degrees i.e. is all resistance. At signal frequencies where we'd like to use it, the impedance is reduced and made more resistive, hence, "shorted turn". Mind, it might be a very "thin" shorted turn -- but that's just a matter of how much resistance it presents!

Comment: I agree that the permeability is unaffected.  As the tape becomes thinner, the frequency increases but at a cost of maximum flux density as the insulation becomes a larger percentage of the total cross section.

Answer (score 9):

Vitroperm is not a metallic material, it's an nanocrystalline alloy (ultra fine grains of FeSi are embedded in Nb and Cu additives). Transformers made of this type of materials are commonly used in SMPS

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that they are indeed used in SMPS. I thought only ferrites were. And why do you think that metals can't be nanocrystalline or amorphous ? "Metal" says nothing about the material microstructure. It does say something about conductivity though. And the conductivity of vitroperm surely qualifies it as a metal.

Comment: More than "nanocrystalline" the important part is "alloy", specially Si and B are nonmetallic elements used in this type of alloys

Comment: Steel also contains carbon and I guess you would consider steel a metal, right ? Most metals, you use everyday are alloyed with "nonmetallic" elements. That doesn't make them nonmetals. VAC themselves call the VITROPERM alloy a metal, if you look at Figure 1 caption in the document linked in the question.

Comment: It is a metallic material. It's a metallic glass with nano-sized crystals formed by annealing. The crystallinity does not define the metallicity; and it's not a composite or matrix formed from conventional (e.g. FeSi) particles.

Comment: Transformers are commonly used as common mode chokes, for filtering. CMCs may be defined as transformers, but aren't often sold that way so it may be worth clarifying that.  They are rarely used for switching power conversion, but have niche applications for signal conversion (ye olde ISDN made excellent use of them).

Comment: I should specify, too: the material in question is such a glass based material.  There are nanocrystalline composites, with low mu suitable for energy storage; but that's different.

Comment: @TimWilliams vitroperm is nanocrystalline. They anneal the amorphous tape to form small crystals (they also do in-field annealing for to set the transverse magn. anisotropy in case of the F type material).

Comment: @tobalt Precisely :)

Answer (score 4):

## TL;DR

**From a quick research I made on the Internet, the explanation may lie in the material being made of nanoparticles.**

## Explanation

Although eddy current losses in *bulk* magnetic materials increase with frequency, as stated in Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eddy_current#Power_dissipation_of_eddy_currents), from an excerpt from a book [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/eddy-current-loss) we infer that nanoparticles behave differently (copy-pasted as image because of lots of formulas):

[image]

<sub>Source: *"Design Criteria of Thermal Seeds for Magnetic Fluid Hyperthermia From Magnetic Physics Point of View"*; Hiroaki Mamiya, Balachandran Jeyadevan, in *"Nanomaterials for Magnetic and Optical Hyperthermia Applications"*, 2019</sub>

Note the last sentence (emphasis mine):

> It is evident that, in reality, **for magnetic particles in nanosize range, eddy current loss can be ignored in comparison with the hysteresis loss**, although it plays a major role in the case of bulk magnetic material placed on top of IH cooker.

This would explain why, that material behaves like it is advertised.

The fact that the material is also manufactured in tiny sheets would further decrease eddy current losses, as lamination do in good old  mains transformers with EI-core made of FeSi alloy.

**EDIT**

Further research led me to this article:

[The influence of Fe nanoparticles on microstructure and magnetic properties of Fe-6.5wt%Si soft magnetic composites](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0925838820315784)

excerpt (emphasis mine):

> Abstract
>
> The effect of Fe nanoparticles with mass fraction of 0-7 wt% on the microstructure and soft magnetic properties of the Fe-6.5 wt%Si soft magnetic composites (SMCs) was investigated. The results show that the pores between Fe-6.5 wt%Si powders can be effectively filled by Fe nanoparticles, thereby correspondingly increasing the density of the SMCs. At the same time, the magnetic permeability of the SMCs mixed with different mass fraction of Fe nanoparticles has improved significantly and exhibits good frequency stability compared with the absence of Fe nanoparticles. It also reveals that **the addition of 1 wt% Fe nanoparticles can reduce the eddy current loss of the SMCs by decreasing its intra-particle eddy current loss**. When the addition of Fe nanoparticles is 3 wt%, **the SMCs exhibits good magnetic properties with high magnetic permeability (increased by 24%) and relatively low core loss**.

which further support my hypothesis.

Comment: in that discussed compound, the bulk conductivity is severly limited by the magnetite. But for vitroperm, the bulk conductivity is given as ~1 MS/m, which includes conduction through all its microstructure (crystals and amorphous phases). So surely the eddies in vitroperm are much stronger than in that discussed iron-magnetite compound.

Comment: @tobalt They also mention **iron** nanoparticles, and their conclusion is the same. It's not a definitive answer, but it shows that if conduction takes places in nanoparticles their dimension plays a role.

Comment: @tobalt And the bulk conductivity is most probably the DC conductivity. Skin effect and proximity effect may change the picture.

Comment: @tobalt see my edit.

Comment: Yes it could be that the skin effect is less severe in a nanocomposite material indeed

Comment: Eddy currents are the same as in any other material of the same conductivity -- the microstructure doesn't (and can't) affect that.  The main thing is the permeability is so high to begin with, and the strip thickness is unusually small (a side effect of the glass production process).

Comment: @TimWilliams That is what I thought too, but those articles that I linked to seem to reach different conclusions. Unfortunately they are both behind a paywall. However I find [this](https://corescholar.libraries.wright.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1000&context=ss5_2013) presentation in which they say (pag.16) that "For NP eddy currents heating can be neglected" because power loss is proportional to the square of the NP diameter. I guess that the overall nanostructure might also be a factor then.

Comment: @TimWilliams Moreover, [in this abstract](https://www.intechopen.com/chapters/82030) they say "At nanoscale, iron oxide’s magnetic and dielectric properties are very different from its bulk properties and can be tuned and enhanced by utilizing different synthesis approaches.". Although they refer to Fe oxides it is a hint that nanoscale may change the picture for other materials as well.

Comment: @TimWilliams And [another article about the use of NPs in S-band applications](https://hal-amu.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-02366403/document) ends with "The low values of loss tangent indicate the low eddy loss of current".

Comment: The first article concerns magnetite (and others I think?, hard to say from just slides unfortunately), a magnetically hard material; presumably that's all hysteresis loss. They seem to be indicating loss for that material is optimized for NPs. Softer materials seem to go the opposite way. Or at least the crystallites in Vitroperm seem to go that way (which as I recall, the papers about the material, said this was unexpected). The other one, the CoFeO's show very low conductivity, comparable to NiZn ferrite, so this is consistent with the bulk property I mentioned.

Comment: In short, those all appear to concern either lone/dispersed NPs, or bound in resin, or sintered whole but still having very high bulk resistivity. Whereas these metals have ~10^6 lower resistivity, over macroscopic dimensions (>10µm), so eddy currents are significant. You can also tell eddy currents / skin effect from the spectrum: skin effect is a diffusion process (Z ~ sqrt(f) or mu ~ sqrt(1/f)).

Answer (score 3):

Simple: the magnetizing inductance doesn't play much role in the LL-Cs resonance.  Core loss is effectively in parallel with the magnetizing current, i.e. the primary or secondary inductance.  If the magnetizing current is small enough -- you really don't care what phase it has!

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7vuGH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is a typical 2nd order nonideal transformer model.  Rp/Rs model DC resistances, Cp/Cs the total winding self-capacitances (there will also be some across the isolation barrier, between the respective ends of the windings), LLp/LLs the leakage inductance (for \$k \rightarrow 1\$, we can approximate it by lumping it all to one side; at lower \$k\$, we might want to use both), Lm the magnetizing inductance, and Rm its loss.  T1 is an ideal transformer with ratio N2/N1.

As a first order model, core loss can be represented simply as a resistance in parallel with the magnetizing inductance.

This approach is also the trick with RF transformers: it's hard to find any material that's meaningfully inductive (not loss dominant) at 100s of MHz, but simply using enough turns that the magnetizing impedance is several times the system impedance (i.e., say 200 ohms compared to the 50 ohm transmission line it connects to) gets you there with <1dB insertion loss, and if that's good enough, who cares, eh?

It may be worth noting that fringing fields and leakage flux (the flux literally leaking out of the core, into space -- not necessarily just that measured between windings) flow thru-plane in these materials (high-mu amorphous/nano. materials are made in strip form only), so will encounter high losses.  This is really only a problem with uneven windings, or around air gaps.

Uneven windings includes the sectoral wind on a toroid, such as commonly used for common mode chokes.  In that case, the differential mode will have higher losses.  (But, that's not at all a problem in that application; it might be valuable if anything.)

These materials are also available in cut C cores, which can be air-gapped for inductor use (energy storage).  This isn't useful at high frequencies for this reason; but the low losses at mains frequency may still make them useful (if a rather expensive choice).

Comment: (Thanks for the comments on the other replies, too). I think you are right about the resonance of the *leakage* inductance with the secondary winding capacitance not requiring the core. Not sure, it explains why the transformer transmits fine up to 250 kHz given a low enough source impedance. I think your 2nd+3rd sentence (*"Core loss...it has!"*) are important but I dont fully get it. Could you expand that bit a little bit ?